# Why webpack addes a './' to my extern library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dagre-d3, dagre

I am using webpack to build both dev and prod code. I added an extern lib correctly in webpack.config.js as below:

```
externals: {
    dagreD3: 'dagre-d3',
}
```

Of course, I also added the src link to index.html correctly as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.min.js"></script>
```

The dev server works fine and I can use the library without problem. But when I build the prod server, for some reason, a './' was appended to the head of the 'src'. So the source become this:

```
src="./https://dagrejs.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.min.js"
```

This breaks the server. I wonder why it is different. Both webpack.prod.config.js and webpack.dev.config.js are loading the same config with the extern:

```
let baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
```

Thank you so much ~!

Comment: look for `publicPath` in  your webpack config. you should see something there.

Comment: @digitake: thanks for the prompt reply. In dev it has `
let devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
});` But in prod, it does not.

Comment: and what if you add that to prod. will it produce same behaviour? I mean just the `publichPath`.

Comment: @digitake: I figured it out. `publicPath` might take effect. But the `./` is added by some other code (hack) in order to make sure it is reading from local dir.